# Ruby: is the Spreadsheet gem thread safe?

Tags: ruby

I'm using Axlsx (which is not thread safe) and I'm looking into switching to Spreadsheet (https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet). However, I don't see anything on the internet about it being thread safe. Does anyone have experience with using threads with the Spreadsheet gem?